# Selecting ALL data from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to display banned users and IP's but they are in two different tables.
I have table for website users and that table contains column 'ban' and another table for banned IP's. So I want something like this:

> SELECT
>
> ipban.ip, ipban.admin, ipban.reason
>
> AND
>
> users.username WHERE ban=1

*(This query isn't correct, I wrote that just to explain my problem)*

And then **display that in a table**.
So, how to do that?

Comment: Use INNER JOIN on a common field. **SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN ip ON users.field = ip.field WHERE users.ban = 1** or something like this.

Comment: Is there any relation between these 2 tables or are they mutually exclusive ?

Comment: Please add information about both tables schema to your question. There must either be a column to join these two tables, e.g., having a user_id in ips table. OR else your database schema explains your system such that a user could be banned OR an IP could be banned. In this case the display table you are trying to create is mis-informative.

Comment: These two tables aren't connected, they do not have any fields that can match.

Comment: Take a look at Elanha's answer, you need UNION

Comment: @OlafDietsche There is a solution...

Comment: If this solves your problem, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UNION, something like this:

```
(SELECT NULL, ipban.ip, ipban.admin, ipban.reason FROM ipban)
UNION ALL
(SELECT users.username,NULL,NULL,NULL FROM users WHERE ban=1)
```

I assume this two tables doesn't have common field to join on.

Comment: That actually worked although I tried a similar query before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ipban.ip, ipban.admin, ipban.reason, users.username FROM ip, users WHERE users.somekey = ipban.somekey and users.ban = 1
```

Assuming `ban` is in the `users` table.

You can also connect the tables using INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT ipban.ip, ipban.admin, ipban.reason, users.username FROM users INNER JOIN ip ON users.somekey = ip.somekey WHERE users.ban = 1
```

To get all columns from both tables, use

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN ip ON users.somekey = ip.somekey WHERE users.ban = 1
```

Comment: Just to mention that these two tables aren't connected and don't have any fields that are matching.

Comment: If the tables aren't connected, then using a UNION to get a full list is not a good solution. Consider having two queries. If the user was found in the users table then you don't have to check on the ip tables and vice versa. Using a UNION also won't give you an index and, as your database grows, this query will be slower and slower.

Comment: UNION works but I've separated it in two queries in two tabs on the page. And by the way, users table is for registered users only without any ip adresses and ipban table is for users that are not registered and do not have username but they are doing something they shouldn't do on the website. So, ip and users tables are not connected and if a user is banned, he is not in the ipban table. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Select 
ipban.ip,ipban.admin,ipban.reason,users.username
from 
ipban Inner Join users
on common attribute (here you should provide a column which is in both the tables)
where ban=1;